# Should questions asking for software recommendation be accepted?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example, [this question](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/188/is-there-an-online-wallet-that-supports-2fa-and-pays-inflation) this question asks for a wallet recommendation. Since this is not directly related to Stellar, should it be off-topic?

Answer (score 5):

While it *is* similar to a software recommendation, it's really a *service* recommendation. Nevertheless, absent some kind of community decision, and guidelines, to the contrary, it's still a *[shopping list](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* question. As a shopping list question, it's not normally going to have timeless value. The subject "a wallet for Stellar" is germane, yet the question, and it's probable, answers, are not a good fit for the format, and goals, of a site on the Stack Exchange network.